# How to resize UICollectionViewCell based on device screen

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionView with a custom cell, however, I am trying to impose constraints on the UICollectionView, so it is always half the width of the screen and half the height of the screen. The one issue I continually encounter is that while the UICollectionView changes according to what device the app is deployed on, the UICollectionViewCells hold the exact same pixel width and height dimensions. This is the code I have tried to implement to make each cell the same height and width as the CollectionView.

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let height = collectionView.frame.height
    let width  = collectionView.frame.width
    return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
}
```

This code, however, doesn't work as the size of the cells are simply the values that are specified in the size inspector for the UICollectionView.

[image]

I'm unable to figure out what I am doing wrong here with my code. Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your collection view cell size is fixed always. So the cell size is not adjust according to screen size.Use view frame size.(remove values from size inspector)

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by remove the values from the size inspector. When I try to remove the values it ends up autofilling to 0, so I don't understand what you mean by remove it. If you could please elaborate that would be much appreciated.

Comment: I mean set it 0 in size inspector and set it programmatically like answer

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not

Comment: can you add the screenshot of result you got

Comment: The size of the UICollectionViewCell is now 0x0 so nothing shows up unfortunately. It isn't reading the value from the method.